# How to pass ContactId to Visualforce page, standardController is Opportunity

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

I have a visualforce page where I want to pass the Contact Id into the visualforce page. This is because I have a flow imbedded in the vf page, which needs a contact id to create Opportunity COntacts.
How do I pass the Contact Id into this flow? I tried using {!$CurrentPage.parameters.conid} but that does not work....

See my code below- thanks:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" RecordSetVar="Opportunities">
   <flow:interview name="CreateOpportunity">
     <apex:param name="var_AccountId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accid}"/> 
     <apex:param name="var_CurrentUserId" value="{!$User.Id }"/> 
     <apex:param name="var_ContactId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.conid}"/> 
   </flow:interview> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Are you passing a parameter called 'conid' to this VF page? From where are you calling this page?

Comment: I am on the Contact Detail Page, and have created a custom 'Create new Opportunity' button which calls this page. I' new to vf so not sure how to pass the conid parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you or on the Contact detail page and you have a button that opens the VF page then you can configure the button to pass the Contact id.

Make sure you are using the content source of the button as URL

```
/apex/yourVFPageName?conId={!Contact.Id}
```